# Работа с интерфейсами в Java

Tags: java

Есть интерфейс:

```
public interface RobotConnectionManager {
    RobotConnection getConnection();
}
```

И есть метод:

```
public static void moveRobot(RobotConnectionManager robotConnectionManager, int toX, int toY) {
    RobotConnection rc = robotConnectionManager.getConnection();
    rc.moveRobotTo(toX, toY);
}
```

Не понимаю, а по сему имеются след. вопросы:

1. при вызове в Main  метода `moveRobot();` не понимаю, что я должен записать в `robotConnectionManager`?
2. `RobotConnection` это тоже интерфейс со своим методом. Как в Java объяснить происходящее в данной строке: `RobotConnection rc = robotConnectionManager.getConnection();` Что нужно почитать, чтобы понять это.

Comment: [Барри Берд - Java для чайников](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/31249416/)

Comment: А так же про ковариантность и контрвариантность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы должны первым параметром передать экземпляр (объект) класса, который реализует интерфейс **RobotConnectionManager**.
2. У объекта хранящегося в переменной `robotConnectionManager` вызывается метод `getConnection`. Этот метод возвращает экземпляр (объект) класса, который реализует интерфейс `RobotConnection`.

Вам стоит прочитать любой учебник по Java и/или [официальное руководство](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).